# R ggplot change point size in stat_qq

Tags: r, ggplot2

I create a QQ plot using ggplot

```
ggplot(deltaIR.df, aes(sample = deltaIR.df[, i])) +
                  stat_qq() + 
                  stat_qq_line() + 
                  labs(title=maturities[i],
                  x = "Normal Quantiles", 
                  y = paste("Sample Quantiles: ", maturities[i], "Interest Rate", sep = " " )) +
                  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 6),
                  axis.title = element_text(size = 6))
```

It works beautifully, except that I can't control the size of the markers for the points on the QQ plot. I need to do this because i have a few thousand data points in my set and they look like a lump when plotted. I have tried changing it by changing the first portion to

```
ggplot(deltaIR.df, aes(sample = deltaIR.df[, i], size = 2)) +
…
```

and the second line to

```
stat_qq(aes(size = 0.2))
```

The first does nothing, and the second plots a large blob to the right of the QQ plot with the words Size 0.2 next to it. How can I just change the size of the points on the QQ plot without cause any other side effects?

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: In your first example, `size = 2` should be an argument to `stat_qq()`, not `ggplot()`. In your second example `size = 2` should _not be inside of_ `aes()` - that makes `ggplot()` try to map to a column named `size`. See `?stat_qq`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the second line to ```stat_qq(size = 0.2)``` and it did exactly what I wanted it to do.